# uwsgi installation gets killed in centos7

Tags: pip, installation, centos7, uwsgi

I have a fresh centos7 on which I'm trying to install a python app. I install gcc, gcc-c++, python3-devel, development tools. And pip is upgraded. This is the console output I'm getting:

> Collecting uwsgi   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz
>   Installing collected packages: uwsgi   Running setup.py install for
>   uwsgi ... \Killed

Running pip in verbose these are the results:

> Found link
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz#sha256=4972ac538800fb2d421027f49b4a1869b66048839507ccf0aa2fda792d99f583
>   (from https://pypi.org/simple/uwsgi/), version: 2.0.18 Given no hashes
>   to check 1 links for project 'uwsgi': discarding no candidates Using
>   version 2.0.18 (newest of versions: 2.0.18) Collecting uwsgi==2.0.18
>   Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-lgj2ifzo   Looking up
>   "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz"
>   in the cache   Current age based on date: 1939   Ignoring unknown
>   cache-control directive: immutable   Freshness lifetime from max-age:
>   365000000   The response is "fresh", returning cached response
>   365000000 > 1939   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz
>   Added uwsgi==2.0.18 from
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz#sha256=4972ac538800fb2d421027f49b4a1869b66048839507ccf0aa2fda792d99f583
>   to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-c6r0ybd7'
>       Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/setup.py) egg_info for package uwsgi
>       Running command python setup.py egg_info
>       running egg_info
>       creating /tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info
>       writing /tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/PKG-INFO
>       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
>       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/top_level.txt
>       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>       reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>       /usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
>         warnings.warn(msg)   Source in /tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi has version 2.0.18, which satisfies requirement uwsgi==2.0.18 from
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz#sha256=4972ac538800fb2d421027f49b4a1869b66048839507ccf0aa2fda792d99f583
>   Removed uwsgi==2.0.18 from
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/1e/3dcca007f974fe4eb369bf1b8629d5e342bb3055e2001b2e5340aaefae7a/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz#sha256=4972ac538800fb2d421027f49b4a1869b66048839507ccf0aa2fda792d99f583
>   from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-c6r0ybd7' Installing
>   collected packages: uwsgi   Created temporary directory:
>   /tmp/pip-record-zslltpm2
>       Running command /opt/myapp/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bkslprsb/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record /tmp/pip-record-zslltpm2/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/myapp/venv/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi
>       /usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
>         warnings.warn(msg)
>       running install
>       using profile: buildconf/default.ini
>       detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include',
>   '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
>       Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
>       detected CPU cores: 40
>       configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.18\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="18" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
>   -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
>       *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
>       [thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
>       [thread 4][gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
>       [thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
>       [thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
>       [thread 5][gcc -pthread] core/master.o
>       [thread 6][gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
>       [thread 7][gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
>       [thread 9][gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
>       [thread 11][gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
>       [thread 13][gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
>       [thread 15][gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
>       [thread 12][gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
>       [thread 19][gcc -pthread] core/config.o
>       [thread 8][gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
>       [thread 10][gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
>       [thread 16][gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
>       [thread 18][gcc -pthread] core/io.o
>       [thread 17][gcc -pthread] core/static.o
>       [thread 23][gcc -pthread] core/websockets.o
>       [thread 21][gcc -pthread] core/spooler.o
>       [thread 24][gcc -pthread] core/snmp.o
>       [thread 25][gcc -pthread] core/exceptions.o
>       [thread 14][gcc -pthread] core/async.o
>       [thread 22][gcc -pthread] core/setup_utils.o
>       [thread 28][gcc -pthread] core/clock.o
>       [thread 27][gcc -pthread] core/init.o
>       [thread 20][gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
>       [thread 36][gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
>       [thread 35][gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
>       [thread 32][gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
>       [thread 29][gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
>       [thread 34][gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
>       [thread 30][gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
>       [thread 31][gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
>       [thread 26][gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
>       [thread 33][gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
>       [thread 38][gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
>       [thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
>       [thread 39][gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
>       [thread 37][gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o Killed

Comment: Not enough memory, perhaps?

Comment: @phd That was it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not having enough memory.